# Python Print Formatting

Tags: python, printing, format

```
dict={'algorithm':'user1','datastr':'user2','hashing':'user3'}
def forums(dict):
    header = ("SubForums","Created By")
    dict_list=dict.items()
    dict_list.insert(0,header)
    i=0
    col_width = max(len(word) for row in dict_list for word in row) + 2 # padding
    for row in dict_list:
            print str(i+1)+"."+"".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)
```

I want to print it like this:

```
SubForums   Created By  
1.Algorithm User1     
2.Hash      user2           
3.datastr   user3
```

It currently prints like dis:

```
  1.SubForums   Created By  
  2.Algorithm   User1     
  3.Hash        user2           
  4.datastr     user3
```

Can anyone please correct my code and help me out. Thank You in advance.

Comment: ... How does it *currently* print?

Comment: dict is a pair of {forumname:createdby}

Comment: @user2205015 post your `dict` in the question body.

Comment: This code doesn't do what you say it does at all. I'm getting this output: `1.SubForums   Created By  
1.datastr     user2       
1.algorithm   user1       
1.hashing     user3`

Comment: i know the output of my code! I know the error lies in the print statement where i gave str(i+1). I couldn't print it in the write way soo asked for help! @nooodl

Comment: Open a new Python file and paste in the code you gave at the top of the post; I guarantee you it will not print what you said it would.

Comment: @nooodl: I'm sorry! dat was the output of some random dictionary i took while executing the code! Really sorry! Edited my question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def forums(d):
    dict_list = [('Subforums', 'Created by')]
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items(), 1):
        k = '{0}. {1}'.format(i, k)
        dict_list.append((k, v))

    col_width = max(len(word) for row in dict_list for word in row) + 2 # padding

    for row in dict_list:
            print ''.join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)
```

(Note how I've changed `dict` to `d`: using a [built-in function's name](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) as a variable is a bad idea!)

Comment: Thank You so much! :) And really sorry for the mistakes! @nooodl